# How to validate angular FormArray in mat-step using [stepControl] for each mat-step

Tags: angular, typescript, material-ui, angular-material

We can bind form control with form groups normally  `[stepControl]="myFormGroup"` in angular material stepper but how to bind with  `FormArray` inside formGroup?

Constructor

```
constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder){}
```

`FormArray` inside `FormGroup`

```
 this.myFormGroup = this._fb.group({
      skills: this._fb.array([this.init()])
    }
```

this is `init` function to create new `formGroup`

```
 init(){
    return this._fb.group({
      skill1: ['', Validators.required],
      skill2: ['', Validators.required],
      skill3: ['', Validators.required],
      skill4: ['', Validators.required],
    })
 }
```

This is my `mat-step` code

```
<mat-stepper linear #stepper>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="myFormGroup" [editable]="isEditable">
    <form [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>

     // Form Fields Goes here

      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
</mat-stepper >
```

Now the problem is how can I set `[stepControl]` to my `FormArray` which is `skills`? if the skills are not valid it should not move to next step

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution.

create a function inside the `component.ts` file

```
get myFormGroupControls() {
    return this.myFormGroup.get('skills') as FormArray
    }
```

Use this function to your mat-step like this

```
[stepControl]="myFormGroupControls"
```